# Android studio stuck at "Downloading Components" on window11

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knElc.png)

I have downloaded Android studio version (android-studio-2023.1.1.27windows) on windows11, 64bit. An issue is downloading is not started. Installation was done successfully. When I click on cancel button then downloading is failed.
I checked on Google, so did changes in bin→idea.property file. This line was added at the end of the file(disable.android.first.run=true) but the issue still exists.

Comment: How long did you wait before clicking cancel? Maybe you just need to wait longer?